# Why can I use Acumatica Oauth2.0 authentication in POSTMAN desktop and not in POSTMAN web or Zapier?

Tags: acumatica, zapier

I am using an Acumatica sandbox account. I was using a self made Zapier app to connect using Oauth2.0. It worked fine for a day and then suddenly stopped working. When trying to reconnect, the Auth window gives a time out error. It is the same when trying to connect using Postman on the web. If I use Postman desktop the Authentication works fine. Can someone please help me troubleshoot? Thanks!